# How to read this array in android from arraylist

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Hey i have this array which my array list is generating

```
 {
id= 197, 
image=http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bottle_pg9.png,
     category=, 
title=example Water 320ML Bottle (Pack of 24) For 6 Months, price=238.50
}
```

but how read this array i tried

```
JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(createArray);
JSONObject data = jsonRootObject.getJSONObject("image");
```

but it gives me error

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 21 of {id= 197, image=http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bottle_pg9.png, category=, title=VOLO example 320ML Bottle (Pack of 24) For 6 Months, price=238.50}
```

Comment: its not in string format. Ask your backend developer to give it in string format.

Comment: it should be like-> "image":"http://volowater.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bottle_pg9.png"

Comment: i am getting from my gridview

String createArray = songsList.get(position).toString();

Comment: i am getting this from the gridview

Comment: @muhammadzeeshan - `Arrays` starts from `[` and not `{`!

Comment: i am reading this xml file

I am reading this xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<music>
   <song>
      <id>198</id>
      <title>Eample Water 320ML Bottle (Pack of 24) For 12 Months</title>
      <price>225.20</price>
      <desc />
      <image>http://Example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bottle_pg9.png</image>
      <category>test</category>
   </song>
</music>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add doable QUOTE "" marks to your XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <music> <song> <id>198</id> <title>"Eample Water 320ML Bottle (Pack of 24) For 12 Months"</title> <price>225.20</price> <desc /> <image>"Example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bottle_pg9.png"
 <category>"test"</category> </song> </music>
```

then read it like this

```
JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(createArray);

String data = jsonRootObject.getString("id");

System.out.println("The data "+data);
```

Comment: hey thanks it works i jist added the quote marks and readed them like this and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

Your input string is not in `JSON` format. Correct format is:

```
 {
    "id" : 197, 
    "image": "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bottle_pg9.png",
    "category": "", 
    "title": "Example Water 320ML Bottle (Pack of 24) For 6 Months",
    "price": 238.50
}
```

Comment: And this is not an answer though!

Comment: I am reading this xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<music>
   <song>
      <id>198</id>
      <title>Eample Water 320ML Bottle (Pack of 24) For 12 Months</title>
      <price>225.20</price>
      <desc />
      <image>http://Example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bottle_pg9.png</image>
      <category>test</category>
   </song>
</music>

Comment: @muhammadzeeshan you cannot parse xml input as JsonObject. You can read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html.

Answer (score 0):

JSON should look like following

```
{id:197,image:'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bottle_pg9.png',category:'',title:'example Water 320ML Bottle (Pack of 24) For 6 Months',price:238.50}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not proper. Try to make proper json format and then try to read with keys it will work.
For json validation using [this site](http://jsonlint.com/)